# Are there any frameworks for DDD?

Tags: java, framework

I would be interested in a light framework that has at least marker annotations for people doing DDD, in Java, for starters.

I know there is Apache Isis https://isis.apache.org/documentation.html that uses some DDD modeling to build an webapp / rest client.

I would interested in 2 things :

- markers that identify Java entities as DDD concepts
- (optional) some documentation generator ( based on these markers )

Answer (score 1):

Apache Isis is indeed a framework for DDD; I'm a committer on the project.

The framework uses DataNucleus as the underlying ORM, currently only for JDO although JPA support is planned soon also.  In JDO an entity is annotated with @PersistenceCapable.  The Isis framework also allows the metamodel to be downloaded, so all entities can also be accessed programmatically, eg via [MetaModelService](http://isis.apache.org/guides/rgsvc/rgsvc.html#_rgsvc_metadata-api_MetamodelService).

In terms of documentation generators, there is lots of stuff that could be done exploiting the metamodel.  We already allow the metamodel to be exported as a spreadsheet (via the "Prototyping" menu), and we also use it to generate a Swagger spec file which means we [automatically provide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkZxRSS0Zwg) a Swagger UI to our REST API.  If you have particular documentation requirements I'm pretty certain they could be accommodated.

HTH